# How to say that I have been many years in the IT field

Tags: meaning-in-context

Currently, I'm starting my resume with

> Throughout more than ten years within the IT I have gained a broad knowledge...

But I don't know whether that sentence makes sense to native speakers. Should I use **in** instead of **within**? Is there a better way to reword this?

Comment: "With over ten years' experience in IT...."

Comment: @Ste I don't want to mention the word **experience**, because often recruiters tend to relate this word with professional experience, and this is not the case. I got a call once from a recruiter telling me that.

Comment: If you don't want to say 'experience' you can just say 'with over ten years in IT'.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to change that.

Comment: Although it's perfectly correct to begin a sentence with a clause I think more direct language is better on a resume. "I have gained a broad knowledge over more than ten years in IT." You could say acquired for gained, or wide for broad. "Within" isn't wrong but sounds a bit heavy here. Throughout isn't correct - it describes a persistent or continuous event over a period of time and clashes with the perfect tense. "I slept throughout the flight." is fine but "I have slept throughout the flight." is wrong.

Comment: @TheMathemagician - Within isn't wrong, but "the" needs to be either eliminated or have the word "field" after IT. Also for a resume, IT should not be initialized, it should be spelled out. "Throughout more than ten years within the information technology field" would be grammatically correct, but you are right that it sounds a bit heavy handed.

Comment: @TheMathemagician I really like more the word *acquire* than *gain* in that context, but I did a fast search and *gain* seems to have more results.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use that kind of full, descriptive sentence in a resume.

If you're doing a CV, you can write things out.

But in a resume, especially an IT-field specific resume, I would be more direct and use something like *10+ years experience in various IT disciplines*.

Resumes are intended to be high-level summaries and a narrative is out of place. But a longer form is appropriate for a CV.

Go with the shorter form if its really a resume; it might not be grammatically correct, but it is business-appropriate.